# Run as testng is not found in eclipse

Tags: testng, eclipse, maven

I have switched to a new branch and created new TestNG XML to run different test suite. But when I tried to run it as a TestNG suite eclipse only suggests run as configurations. I have set the suite path in TestNG but still not getting run as TestNG.

I have tried maven clean and project update as well.  TestNG is already installed in eclipse.

What can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

There are several possible reasons why the "Run as TestNG" option may not be available in Eclipse:

1. TestNG plugin is not installed: To use TestNG in Eclipse, you need to have the TestNG plugin installed. If it is not installed, you can install it from the Eclipse marketplace.
2. Incorrect TestNG library version: Ensure that you are using the correct version of the TestNG library that is compatible with your version of Eclipse.
3. Invalid project setup: If your project is not set up as a TestNG project, you won't see the "Run as TestNG" option. You can set up your project as a TestNG project by right-clicking on your project and selecting the "Configure" option and then selecting "Convert to TestNG."
4. Incorrect build path: Ensure that the TestNG library is included in your project build path. You can add the library to the build path by right-clicking on your project and selecting "Build Path" and then "Configure Build Path."
5. Broken installation of TestNG: If you have installed the TestNG plugin, but it is not working, you may need to reinstall it.

Try these solutions and see if they resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

1. Help--->Install new software-->already installed --->TestNG (All)---> Uninstall ---> restart now (Eclipse will restart)
2. After restart again Help-->Install new software --> Clicks on 'Add' ---> Name TESTNG URL - https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site/7.4.0/
   ---> Ok
3. After install restart now Eclipse
4. You got the TestNG